# Docker requires sudo to run

Tags: docker

When I try to run any docker command, for example `docker ps`, I'm getting this error:

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon
>   socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/json: dial unix
>   /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

So I manage to run it using sudo:

```
sudo docker ps
```

But I want to be able to run that without sudo.

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user)

Comment: Can you share the search terms you used when you Googled for the resolution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to achieve the desired result you have to do the *post-installation steps* described in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/):

1. Create the docker group.

   ```
   $ sudo groupadd docker
   ```
2. Add your user to the docker group.

   ```
   $ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
   ```
3. Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.